# If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form control must be defined as ‘standalone’ in ngModelOptions

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-forms

I use angular 9. my aim  when i click in login button iit redirect me
to dashboard if login is success,otherwise it redirectme to login
page.  when i enter my username and pasword and click on login button
it show an error  If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the
name attribute must be set or the form control must be defined as
‘standalone’ in ngModelOptions

```
tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form
      control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.

      Example 1: <input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" name="first">
      Example 2: <input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
     at Function.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.TemplateDrivenErrors.missingNameException
(forms.js:4830)
    at NgModel.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.NgModel._checkName
(forms.js:5158)
    at NgModel.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.NgModel._checkForErrors
(forms.js:5143)
    at NgModel.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.NgModel.ngOnChanges
(forms.js:5046)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:22777)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:31612)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:31574)     at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:32211)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:32171)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (LoginComponent.html:16) View_LoginComponent_0 @ LoginComponent.html:15 LoginComponent.html:16
ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_
loginc.component.html
```

---

*Code*

```html
<div class="app-body">
    <main class="main d-flex align-items-center">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 mx-auto">
                <div class="card-group">
                <div class="card p-4">
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <form>
                        <h1>Login</h1>
                        <p class="text-muted">Sign In to your account</p>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" [(ngModel)]="username" autocomplete="username" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group mb-4">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="icon-lock"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"[(ngModel)]="password" autocomplete="current-password" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <button type="button" (click)=dologin class="btn btn-primary px-4">Login</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6 text-right">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link px-0">Forgot password?</button>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card text-white bg-primary py-5 d-md-down-none" style="width:44%">
                    <div class="card-body text-center">
                    <div>
                        <h2>Sign up</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary active mt-3">Register Now!</button>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the "name" property is missing in the tags as rightly pointed out by @mike :

eg:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" name="first">
```

or needs to be defined as standalone in ngModelOptions
eg:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
```

Doing one of the above steps the error will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `[(ngModel)]` like this you will need to set `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"`

```
<div class="app-body">
    <main class="main d-flex align-items-center">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 mx-auto">
                <div class="card-group">
                <div class="card p-4">
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <form>
                        <h1>Login</h1>
                        <p class="text-muted">Sign In to your account</p>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" [(ngModel)]="username" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" autocomplete="username" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group mb-4">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="icon-lock"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"[(ngModel)]="password" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" autocomplete="current-password" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <button type="button" (click)=dologin class="btn btn-primary px-4">Login</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6 text-right">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link px-0">Forgot password?</button>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card text-white bg-primary py-5 d-md-down-none" style="width:44%">
                    <div class="card-body text-center">
                    <div>
                        <h2>Sign up</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary active mt-3">Register Now!</button>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</div>
```

More information here: https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel

Comment: wher set this [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" login.component.html/app.module.ts/app.routeing

Comment: @Mike, you only need use standalone if your [(ngModel)] is INSIDE a FormGroup, else it's only necesary give a name, e.g. `<input name="myinput" [(ngModel)]="..">`

Comment: Hm, I was assuming it was because of the error message, but you're right. Why'd it throw that error then though? Either one should work, iam not sure what the difference between the 2 options is.